# How to Download Locale TTS

Tags: javascript, download, google-api, text-to-speech

I wanted to ask how you could add a button to download the audio according to the text entered. If there is no possibility of doing so, any recommendation? Attached the code of what I have advanced.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('dia_final') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Mensaje</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="text">
      <a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto!</a>
    </div>
    <audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
    <script>
      $("a.say").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $("input[name=text]").val();
        responsiveVoice.speak(text, "Spanish Female");
        text = encodeURIComponent(text);
        var url = "http://"
      })
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php` shall facilitate your requirement. For instance the URL `https://code.responsivevoice.org/getvoice.php?t=hello%20world&tl=en-US` dispenses the audio *hello world*.

A mundane solution to achieve an one-click download via pure client-side scripting would be to fetch the audio file utilising AJAX, convert it into an object URL and use an anchor element to trigger the download.

However, since the endpoint is served without CORS headers the use of a service equivalent of `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` would be required.

I have drafted a specimen at https://jsfiddle.net/u2chbxq7/ which shall serve as a roadmap.

Comment: Hello Ashen Could you help me apply? Pls

Comment: @RenatoCarcamo I have update the answer; hope it shall help!